# 2D Dynamic Lighting in Java

Tags: java, 2d, lighting

I am making a game that has campfire objects. What I want to do is to brighten all pixels in a circle around each campfire. However, looping through every pixel and changing those within the radius is not all that efficient and makes the game run at ~7 fps. Ideas on how to either make this process efficient or simulate light differently?

I haven't written the code for the fires but this is the basic loop to check each pixel/change its brightness based on a number:

```
public static BufferedImage updateLightLevels(BufferedImage img, float light)
{
    BufferedImage brightnessBuffer = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);

    brightnessBuffer.getGraphics().drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);

    for(int i = 0; i < brightnessBuffer.getWidth(); i++)
    {
        for(int a = 0; a < brightnessBuffer.getHeight(); a++)
        {
            //get the color at the pixel
            int rgb = brightnessBuffer.getRGB(i, a);

            //check to see if it is transparent
            int alpha = (rgb >> 24) & 0x000000FF;

            if(alpha != 0)
            {
                //make a new color
                Color rgbColor = new Color(rgb);

                //turn it into an hsb color
                float[] hsbCol = Color.RGBtoHSB(rgbColor.getRed(), rgbColor.getGreen(), rgbColor.getBlue(), null);

                //lower it by the certain amount
                //if the pixel is already darker then push it all the way to black
                if(hsbCol[2] <= light)
                    hsbCol[2] -= (hsbCol[2]) - .01f;
                else
                    hsbCol[2] -= light;

                //turn the hsb color into a rgb color
                int rgbNew = Color.HSBtoRGB(hsbCol[0], hsbCol[1], hsbCol[2]);

                //set the pixel to the new color
                brightnessBuffer.setRGB(i, a, rgbNew);
            }


        }
    }

    return brightnessBuffer;
}
```

I apologize if my code is not clean, I'm self taught.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: However, I would suggest that you consider symmetry: if the pixel at (x, y) is within the circle centred on (0, 0), so are (-x, y), (x, -y) and (-x, -y).

Comment: Not necessarily jonrsharpe , I think that alternative approaches are more important here than just code golfing his implementation.

Comment: Why not http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

I can give you lots of approaches.

You're currently rendering on the CPU, and you're checking every single pixel. That's hardcore brute force, and brute force isn't what the CPU is best at. It works, but as you've seen, the performance is abysmal.

I'd point you in two directions that would massively improve your performance:

Method 1 - Culling. Does every single pixel really need to have its lighting calculated? If you could instead calculate a general "ambient light", then you could paint most of the pixels in that ambient light, and then only calculate the really proper lighting for pixels closest to lights; so lights throw a "spot" effect which fades into the ambient. That way you're only ever performing checks on a few of the pixels of the screen at a time (the circle area around each light). The code you posted just looks like it paints every pixel, I'm not seeing where the "circle" dropoff is even applied.

Edit:

Instead, sweep through the lights, and just loop through local offsets of the light position.

```
for(Light l : Lights){

for(int x = l.getX() -LIGHT_DISTANCE, x< l.getX() + LIGHT_DISTANCE, y++){

for(int y = l.getY() - LIGHT_DISTANCE, y < l.getY() + LIGHT_DISTANCE, y++){

//calculate light
int rgb = brightnessBuffer.getRGB(x, y);
//do stuff
}

}
```

You may want to add a check with that method so overlapping lights don't cause a bunch of rechecks, unless you DO want that behavior (ideally those pixels would be twice as bright)

Method 2 - Offhand calculation to the GPU. There's a reason we have graphics cards; they're specifically built to be able to number crunch those situations where you really need brute force. If you can offload this process to the GPU as a shader, then it'll run licketysplit, even if you run it on every pixel several times over. This will require you to learn graphics APIs however, but if you're working in java, LibGDX makes it very painless to render using the GPU and pass off a couple shaders to the GPU.

Comment: Well that was just rough code. If I were to do it that way which I am not, I would cross check every pixel position with each light position, then change the light based on the distance from the source. But as you said, performance is abysmal. In your first approach, how would you go about finding the pixels closest to the light, I can't think of a way other than stepping through the pixels to see if they are close.

Comment: Updated the question to answer you since comment formatting sucks.
How about an upvote? :P

Answer (score 0):

I am uncertain about the way in which you are going about calculating light values, but I do know that using the BufferedImage.getRGB() and BufferedImage.setRGB() methods is very slow.

I would suggest accessing the pixels of the BufferedImage directly from an array (much faster IMO)

to do this:

```
BufferedImage lightImage = new BufferedImage(width,height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Raster r = lightImage.getRaster();
int[] lightPixels = ((DataBufferInt)r.getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

Now, changing any pixel in this array will show on your image. Note that the values used in this array are color values in the format of whatever format you defined your image with.

In this case it is TYPE_INT_ARGB meaning you will have to include the alpha value in the number when setting the coloar (RRGGBB**AA**)

Since this array is a 1D array, it is more difficult to access pixels using x and y co-ordinates. The following method is an implementation of accessing pixels from the lightPixels array more easily.

```
public void setLight(int x, int y,int[] array,int width, int value){
    array[width*y+x] = value;
}
```

*note: *width* is the width of your level, or the width of the 2D array your level might exist as, if it was a 2D array.

You can also get pixels from the lightPixels array with a similar method, just excluding the  *value* and returning the `array[width*y+x]`.

It is up to you how you use the setLight() and getLight() methods but in the cases that I have encountered, using this method is much faster than using getRGB and setRGB.

Hope this helps